# Does HCL OneTest Data support the import of schema or sample data set from Mysql, and Mongo DB?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, import, schema

Can I import a schema from Mysql, and Mongo DB into HCL OneTest Data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, HCL OneTest Data supports the import of schema from MongoDB and MySQL.